# Postgres - sequential counting numeric field (Italian counting)

Tags: database, counter

I am building a system to generate transport documents.
The table has the following fields:

```
ID - Numeric And primary key
Reference_Client - Numeric reference to the customer
Date- Current Date
Code
```

In Italy, every transport document has sequential number. `Code` needs to start from 0 and increments for each `Date`.

How can I set `Code` to obtain automatically incremented number?

[image: screen shot of a table of data showing rows of data where the sequence number restarts at 1 on each new date]

Comment: If it increments daily (is this true?), isn't it just the number of days between the "first" document and the given document's date?

Comment: @LucaAngelino Do you mean that you sequentially number each document produced through the day (1, 2, 3, …), and restart the sequence each day (1, 2, 3, … on Monday | 1, 2, 3, … on Tuesday | and so on)?

Comment: @BasilBourque Yes :-) Now I have add an table exsample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a sequence that restarts at `1` on each new day.

## Time Zone

So the first task is the define what you mean by a new day. For any given moment, the date varies around the world by time zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in Paris is still “yesterday” in Montréal.

So you need to pick a time zone in which “today” makes sense for your applications. Perhaps that means [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). For example, Stack Overflow uses UTC when showing your activity on this site by each day. So a new “day” on Stack Overflow starts at 4 or 5 PM in the afternoon for those of us on the west coast of North America.

If not UTC, learn your true time zone. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviations often seen in the media, such as `EST` or `IST`. These are neither standardized nor unique! Use [proper time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), consisting of `continent/region` such as `America/Montreal`.

Use a good date-time library. Unfortunately that is rare. For Java, use java.time framework built into Java 6 & 7 (with back-ports available). Be sure to keep the [`tz` database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) up-to-date in that library, to accommodate the all-too-frequent changes that politicians enjoy making. A database with good support for date-time may have its own copy of the `tz` database that may need to be updated.

By the way, know that the day does *not* always start at the time `00:00:00.0`. In a few time zones, [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) change-over happens at midnight.

## Sequence

Now you need to generate a sequence of numbers. There are usually two ways to do that:

- Use a sequence generator in your database.
- Roll-your-own sequence generator.

If possible, best to use your database server’s sequence generator. Managing a sequence is trickier than you may expect. [Concurrency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_(computer_science)) is always a tough nut to manage correctly. You have to make sure the sequence does not hand out the same number twice. And when [transactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) rollback, you may need to dispose of the obtained sequence number as another concurrent transaction may have already moved on to the next number. Or perhaps you *do* want to recycle such not-actually-used numbers (a policy your app needs to decide), which means storing those to be used next rather than generate a successive number.

I suggest looking at your database’s capabilities. If your database offers a sophisticated reliable sequence generator, and your database offers a server-side programming language such as [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html) in [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org), then I suggest writing a method to be called by your apps to generate the sequence-per-date.

Create a sequence with a name incorporating the date. The name of the sequence object managed by your database could be something like `transport-seq-2016-05-12`. When your method it called, it determines today’s date, assembles the string “transport-seq-” plus a string representing the date. I suggest sticking with standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, `YYYY-MM-DD` for that string. Query the metadata of your database for a sequence object carrying that name, or alternatively, try using that sequence and trap for the error that occurs with a nonexistent sequence.

When a sequence is not found, that means the date has rolled over. You have two options:

- Rename the old sequence with the new string holding today’s date, and reset the sequence to `0` (or `1`).
- Create a new sequence object, defaulting to `0` (or `1`). Leave the old sequence objects to slowly accumulate while laying fallow.

Both approaches have concurrency issues. Keep in mind that the line of code that determines today’s date is distinct, and runs separate (non-atomically), from the code that looks for an existing sequence. And similarly, the code looking for an existing sequence runs separately (non-atomically) from the code that would be renaming the sequence or creating a fresh sequence.

### Rename sequence

If renaming, you need to be sure your database can handle the sequence-renaming in a transaction-safe manner. And you need to handle the possibility that one thread (Thread A) is about to rename-and-reset the sequence, gets suspended, another thread (Thread B) on its own does the rename-and-reset, then Thread A continues on its way to *again* rename-and-reset. Your code needs to prevent or resolve this A-B-A problem; probably this means handling the error that occurs when A tries to rename a sequence that no longer exists with the old name. And there may be other concurrency issues I’ve not thought of. For one thing, the sequence-naming needs to be executed by the database in an atomic fashion, completing after any other usage of the sequence and completing before any other usage of the sequence. Furthermore, the sequence rename-and-reset are two different operations that are not going to be atomic, so you need some kind of protection, likely a [semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29).

### Create sequence

Creating a new sequence might be safer, with less concurrency issues. But I suspect you will still need some kind of semaphore protection around creation of the new fresh sequence, in similar A-B-A problem as described above. Thread A could have determined a new sequence is needed, but then get interrupted. Meanwhile Thread B runs, also determines the need for new sequence, creates sequence, and that Thread A continues only to encounter an error as the sequence already exists. Such concurrency issues can be handled properly, you just need to be thorough and do the work to avoid a runtime failure in production. And, one more chore: you will probably want to do an occasional clean-up operation to delete old sequence objects.

### Roll-your-own sequence

If your database lacks a capable sequence generator, create your own. Create a table named something like `transport_sequence_`. This table can have either exactly one row or many, following the same logic above about renaming or creating a fresh one.

Either way, I suggest implementing a server-side method in the database to be called by app rather than the apps trying to manage the sequence.

This table has two columns, a date-only type, and a integer type. The integer represents the last-number-used (or next-number-used depending on your tastes). If renaming, alter the date when a new day rolls over. Or create a new row with the new day’s date. Use the transaction & concurrency features of your database to increment the number in the integer field of the row. Easier said than done properly.

If you have a policy of re-using any canceled numbers to avoid leaving holes in the sequence, then add another related child table with one row being added for each recycled number. A row is deleted when its number is handed out to another transaction.